# How to generate a Tink key from a user-provided password

Tags: tink

I want to [store a keyset](https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/docs/JAVA-HOWTO.md#storing-keysets), and would like the file to be encrypted with key produced from a user-provided "master password". And of course, at a later point I'd like to, given the same master password, be able to [load that keyset](https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/docs/JAVA-HOWTO.md#loading-existing-keysets) by decrypting the file.

It seems that I need an `Aead`, which I can generate from a `KeysetHandle` with `AeadFactory.getPrimitive(keysetHandle)`. But how can I produce a `KeysetHandle` from a "master password"?

(And for the context of this question, getting that key from a Key Management Systems, instead of producing it "out of thin air" from a master password, isn't an option.)

Answer (score 0):

An `Aead` can be created as follows (here done from Scala):

```
val password: String = "..."
val aead = {
  val messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
  messageDigest.update(password.getBytes(CharsetNames.Utf8))
  val key256Bit = messageDigest.digest()
  val key128Bit = key256Bit.take(16)
  new AesGcmJce(key128Bit)
}
```

A few comments:

- I'd prefer the key to be based on a 32-bit digest, but the cipher picked by Tink in this case throws an exception when provided with a 32-bit key, hence the shortening to a 16-bit key.
- It seems [shortening the key this way is ok](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/34797/49208) from a hash weakness perspective.